# Access Sinatra settings from helper module

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a class `App` that inherits from `Sinatra::Base` and a module `AppHelper` that I use with `helpers AppHelper` in `App`. How do I access settings defined in `App` from `AppHelper`?

Here is some example code:

```
# app.rb
require "sinatra"
require "./helper"

class App < Sinatra::Base

  set :message, "Hello, World!"
  helpers AppHelper

  get "/" do
    helper_method
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  App.run! port: 4567
end
```

And here is the helper:

```
# helper.rb
module AppHelper

  def helper_method
    settings.message
  end
end
```

Unfortunatley this produces

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `message' for App:Class
```

How can I access the settings from my helper module?

Comment: Your code works okay for me, I don’t think the order of the `set` and `helpers` calls is the problem. Also you should require `sinatra/base` and not plain `sinatra`.

Comment: I guess my example is crap... I should have cleaned up my real code  and posted that instead of some made up example code. I don't want to delete this question because I have already accepted an answer.

Comment: Also add require 'sinatra/base' to the helper modules. http://www.sitepoint.com/using-sinatra-helpers-to-clean-up-your-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try switching the order of your dependencies:

```
helpers AppHelper
set :message, "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I will accept your answer as soon as I can. It doesn't work for my real app though because my real code differs a bit from my example. I configure all my settings in config.ru. I will create a seperate answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

My real code is a bit different than my example (I thought it wouldn't matter). I define my settings in config.ru so dax's answer does not work for my app. I was able to solve that problem by using `Sinatra::Application.settings` instead of `settings`.